# Angular2 - Waiting for service variable to be initialized

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Application

- MapViewComponent
- SearchComponent (requires an object of the MapViewComponent)
- MapService

So far, I placed the `SearchComponent` inside the `MapViewComponent`s template so I was able to pass it to the `SearchComponent` by using `@Inject(forwardRef(() => MapViewComponent))` . But as the search component should be displayed somewhere else within the layout / HTML DOM, I think I have to use a service to pass the `MapViewComponent` to the Search.

MapViewComponent.ts:

```
export class MapViewComponent {
    @Output() onMapViewCreated = new EventEmitter();

    private _view: any = null;      

    constructor(private mapService: MapService, private elRef: ElementRef) {
    }          

    ngOnInit() {
        this._view = new MapView({
            container: this.elRef.nativeElement.firstChild,
            map: this._mapService.map,
            center: [5.44, 36.947974],
            rotation: 0,
            autoResize: true
        })

        this._view.then((view) => {
            this.onMapViewCreated.next(view);
            this._mapService.setView(view);
        });
```

SearchComponent.ts:

```
export class SearchComponent {

    constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private mapService: MapService ) {
       var view = mapService.getView();
    }
}
```

MapService.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class MapService {
     public setView(mv: MapView){
        this.view = mv;    // what do I have to do here..?
     }  

     public getView(){
        return this.view;  // .. and here?
     }
}
```

It obviously wont work like that, because `getView()` might get called before `setView()`.

Comment: You should store an`Observable<MapView>` or a `Promise<MapView>` as view, then you'll return the Observable/promise in your getter, this allows you to do `getView().then(your function...)` and resolve your promise/emit in your observable once the view is set. edit: What is MapView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a [`Subject`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md) (either `BehaviorSubject` or `ReplaySubject`). The `Subject` will act as both a producer and consumer. The consumer of it can subscribe to it, just like an observable. And the producer can use it to emit messages to consumers. For example

```
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs/ReplaySubject'

@Injectable()
export class MapService {

  private _currentMapView = new ReplaySubject<MayView>(1);

  setCurrentView(mv: MapView){
    this._currentView.next(mv);
  }

  get currentMapView$() {
    return this._currentMapView.asObservable();
  }
}
```

The subscriber just needs to suscribe

```
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

export class SearchComponent {
  sub: Subscription;
  view: MapView;

  constructor(private elRef:ElementRef, private mapService: MapService ) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.mapService.currentMapView$.subscribe(view => {
      this.view = view;
    })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub) {
      this.sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

The `MapViewComponent` just needs to call the `setCurrentView`, and it will be handled by the subscribers automatically when it's sent

**See Also:**

- [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40456451/2587435) for a brief description about difference between `Subject`/`BehaviorSubject`/`ReplaySubject`