# Angular 2: Using HTTP requests with Observables to search a database

Tags: angular, angular2-observables

I'm following Angular 2's tutorial on using HTTP requests with Observables to search a database. Here is a link to the specific tutorial: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html

You can do a search for "Search-by-name" to find the area of the tutorial I'm referring to.

Here is the code in question:

```
this.heroes = this.searchTerms
  .debounceTime(300)        // wait for 300ms pause in events
  .distinctUntilChanged()   // ignore if next search term is same as previous
  .switchMap(term => term   // switch to new observable each time
    // return the http search observable
    ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
    // or the observable of empty heroes if no search term
    : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))
  .catch(error => {
    // TODO: real error handling
    console.log(error);
    return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
  });
```

I was able to make appropriate changes to this code to get it to work with my application, but I am wondering how to invoke functions for when it successfully returns data and when it is unable to find what you're looking for. It's probably relatively simple to do, but I'm having trouble figuring it out and am not quite sure how to search for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am wondering how to invoke functions for when it successfully returns data and when it is unable to find what you're looking for

You still need to subscribe. Nothing happens until you subscribe.

```
this.searchTerms
  .debounceTime(300)  
  .distinctUntilChanged()
  .switchMap(term => term  
    ? this.heroSearchService.search(term)
    : Observable.of<Hero[]>([]))
  .catch(error => {
    return Observable.of<Hero[]>([]);
  })
  .subscribe(heroes => {
    this.heroes = heroes;
    doOtherStuff();
  });
```

This is where you can handle "success", "error", and "complete" cases. The subscribe takes these three callbacks, respectively.

```
 .subscribe(
   (heroes) => {},  // success
   (error) => {},   // error
   () => {}         // completed/always
 );
```

> when it is unable to find what you're looking for

Just check if the `heroes` from the subscribe "success" is empty.

Comment: This is giving me the following build error: Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<VarietyTypeGroup[]>'

Comment: One of the changes I made to get it to work with my application was changing Hero[] to VarietyTypeGroup[] and changing the name of the service, otherwise it is all the same.

Comment: Because you can't assign the result to that. The result is a Subscription after you subscribe. You should do any assignment in the success callback. And have the class member not an observable of the array, but just the array

Comment: Also check [this out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40469735/2587435). It shows how you should handle the Subscription. It should be cleaned up when the component is destroyed

Comment: I replaced the first subscribe function with the second one you wrote and it works now.

Comment: So to clean it up when the component is destroyed, do I do something like this? ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.heroes) {
      this.heroes.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

Comment: Or would it be: ngOnDestroy() { if (this.searchTerms) { this.searchTerms.unsubscribe(); } }

Comment: No, it should be `this.sub = this.searchTerms.debounce().subscribe()`. `this.sub` is the field in the class, like in the example. Then unsubscribe from `this.sub`