# Call ViewChild methods with updated nested value in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using the [angular2-progressbar](https://github.com/ksachdeva/angular2-progressbar) library to display some circular progress bars in my app. I have a list of inventory items and a service that updates the inventory list. Each inventory item component gets the updated inventory value from a key in the inventory list like so:

```
export class InventoryComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(CircleProgressComponent): circleComp: CircleProgressComponent;
  @Input() deviceKey: string;
  private circleOptions: ShapeOptions { /* from angular2-progressbar example */ }
  constructor(private inventoryService: InventoryService) { }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.deviceList = this.inventoryService.deviceList;
    setInterval(() => {
      // this value will be 0 or 1
      this.circleComp.animate(this.deviceList[this.deviceKey]);
    }, 2000);
  }
}
```

While this does work, it seems very hacky to me to have the interval check only after every 2 seconds when the actual value in the template itself gets updated immediately whenever `inventoryService` updates its device list.

I tried implementing `OnChange`, but there are two problems:

1. The initial `change` fires before the view init lifecycle, i.e. before `circleComp` is available. This breaks things.
2. Because `this.deviceList` is an object and its properties get updated internally, `OnChange` does not get fired anyway. Instead I can do an additional check using `ngDoCheck` -- this does work, but it is a lot more verbose and #1 still causes a problem.

Is there any way to start performing checks *after* the view has loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to start performing checks after the view has loaded?

Use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook (override `ngAfterViewInit`). This is when the `@ViewChild` is available

I think there may be a better solution than polling `deviceList`. You could use a `Subject` in the service. This will act like an observer and observable, so you can subscribe to it on one end, and publish on the other. For example

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject'

class InventoryService {
  private _inventoryList = new BahaviorSubject<any>({ initialize with data })

  inventoryList$ = this._inventoryList.asObservable();

  set inventoryList(list: any) {
    this._inventoryList.next(list);
  }
}
```

Now you can just subscribe to the list. And whenever you want to update it, just use the setter, and all the subscribers will get the updated list. No need to poll.

Subscriber

```
service.inventoryList$.subscribe(list => {})
```

Publisher

```
service.inventoryList = newList
```

**See also:**

- [Using Subjects](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/gettingstarted/subjects.md)

Comment: What is the difference between the `BehaviorSubject` and `Subject`? Also there will be multiple components subscribed to the same inventory list ... will this still work correctly?

Comment: Yes it will work as expected (every subscriber seeing the same value). See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40456451/2587435) for brief (yet pretty concise explanation)

Comment: Adding `subscribe` in the `ngAfterViewInit` worked great. Is it also possible to subscribe in views? I have a view that uses `inventoryService.someProperty` but if that data is being updated asynchronously I would prefer to use that if possible

Comment: You could try to use the `async` pipe. `inventoryService.someProperty | async`. If that doesn't work, maybe just add a property in the component class and update it when you subscribe